# Update comma separated list in mysql with unique ID

Tags: php, mysql, php-7.3

In my DB (mysql) I have a table 'ads' which contains info about different ads on a website.
I want to track unique clicks on any ad.
So I created a field '`item_discount_userid`' (`mediumtext`) in table ads and want to store users IDs comma separated in that field (like '1,13,44,22,45')
And on click I want to check is user ID is already in that list or not.
If not I want to add user ID to that list and send him mail. Else - do nothing.
Can some one help me with PHP code (7.3 php)?

To be short I want something like this:

```
if 'user_id' is in 'item_discount_userid' 
{
}
else
{
add user_id in 'item_discount_userid';
}
```

Sorry for my poor English, and I am a newbee in PHP. Tried searching, tried some answers but failed. Thanks ahead!

Comment: Do not store the data that way. Create another table to store user-clicks.

Comment: Can you tell me the best way to make a new table? I have ads (a,b,c,etc), and users (1,2,3,etc)
I need to track only first click of any user on any ad.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE foo (ad_id int, user_id int, clickdate datetime, etc)`???

Comment: In result i will store all unique clicks in separate strings? Like
ad_id 1, user_id 1
ad_id 1, user_id 2
ad_id 1, user_id 3
ad_id 2, user_id 1
ad_id 2, user_id 2

Instead of 
ad_id 1, user_id 1,2,3,4
ad_id 2, user_id 1,2,3,4

Comment: You will not store anything as string. Store clicks as rows in database, one row represents one click, you could choose not to insert a row if there is a duplicate. You should ask a different if you want suggestions about how to design the table... comments are not for extended discussion.

Comment: if you do by this method then lot work you will need to do, well it is possible by either ways